# When submitting a major revision, does it matter whether the revised manuscript or the response to reviewers appears first?

Tags: publications, research-process, peer-review, journals, editors

I submitted a major revision for an article to a World Scientific journal today. However I am in a confused state.
I had to submit two documents: 1. Revised Manuscript, 2. Response to Reviewers, both in PDF format.

**Though I submitted both the documents, I find that in the complete PDF that I submitted to the journal, my "Revised Manuscript" is attached first and then the "Response to Reviewers" is attached second.  The complete PDF which I submitted is of 15 pages.
In pages 1-10 the revised manuscript is attached, and from 11-15 the comments are attached**.

I think it should be the other way round, i.e. first "Response to Reviewers" and then "Revised Manuscript" should have been attached.

I wrote to the editor about this but no one replied.

I am worried that the reviewers will find me careless because of this mistake. Will it have any effect on my manuscript?

**Is it possible for someone to please let me know how the revised manuscript is sent to the reviewer? Does the reviewer receive everything (revised manuscript+comments) as a single PDF file or are  they sent separately?**

This is my first time, so I am not completely sure how the process works. Can someone who has done reviews for a journal (I am sure there are many here) please help?

Comment: I don't think anyone will mind the order of the documents, nor find anything about that impolite.

Comment: @Sursula; okay, my only concern is will the Reviewer be able to find "Reply to Reviewer" which is attached after the revised manuscript as a PDF? I am worried with that,because the PDF of "Reply to Reviewer"  contains important information about my manuscript

Comment: I think the order can in principle be important as for reading the answers first can positively affect the reading of the ms. However you have sent the response as a separate file, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ordering really doesn't matter. It's a trivial matter to scroll to the other section, or to bring up a new window to read both at the same time. Reviewers receive both the revised manuscripts and the comments as a single file, but if any reviewers have complained that the comments come before the revised manuscript (or vice versa), I have not seen them, and I have interacted with many, many reviewers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was just wondering that whether Reviewers receive two files as separate files (PDF) as a zip file or it is two PDF  files one merged after the other?

Comment: @Math_Freak probably the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, we receive the entire file; revised manuscript plus your comments.  If your comments are missing, we may ask the editor if it 'looks' like it should be attached to the pdf or email.

It does not matter whether your comments come first or after the revised paper; my preference is for the comments to come first.